# Rolle theorem for the Number of roots of a real function

Tags: real-analysis, roots, rolles-theorem

I know I can apply the theorem for the polyniomials to know the number of roots. In fact polynomials are continous whatever $[a,b]$ considered and derivable whatever $(a,b)$.

If the function considered is not a polynomial can I apply this? I thought that I have to verify if the function is continous whatever $[a,b]$ in the domain and derivable whatever $(a,b)$ in the domain? It is right?

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8588/290189) I have tried to improve the readability of your question by improving the [$\rm \LaTeX$](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189) code. It is possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question.  Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.

Comment: That's ok! Thanks

Comment: To apply this theorem, you don't need the function to be a polynomial.  You only need two things: 1. continuity on the closed interval 2. differentiability on the open interval.

Comment: But if the function is defined in all $\mathbb{R}$ it is necessary that exists one closed interval with those properties or they must hold for each closed interval in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Oops I missed one thing in my previous comment: of course you need $f(a) = f(b)$.  Just take any open interval containing your given closed interval to get your desired conclusion.

Comment: log is strictly increasing, so you may take that away.  $x \mapsto \sqrt{x+1} + \sqrt{1-x}$ is continuous on the domain where it's defined b/c everything inside is composed of elementary functions.  Observe that it's symmetric about the $y$-axis, and $f(0) = 2$, $f(\pm1) = \sqrt2$.  Some simple differentiation would allows us to see that its strictly increasing on the left half.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: actually there are other functions that are differentiable, and the theorem is general and doesn't restrict to polynomials.

Ex.: $e^x+e^{-x}$ satisfies this problem, as there are two points $a, b$ in some interval such that $f(a) = f(b)$, for some $c$, such that $a<c<b$, and as the derivative changes its sign, then **Rolle's Theorem** will be satisfied.

Antoher Hint: one thing interesting to note is that if the derivative doesn't change the sign, then it means there aren't two equal values for $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, which means, for example, that you can only have a real root, for the $f$
being zero in some interval.